# Hive : Filter array of maps

Tags: java, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table column as

```
col1                array<map<string,string>>
```

this column contains values as

```
[
    {'a':1,'b':2},
    {'a':1,'c':3},
    .
    .
    .
]
```

now the keys in the inner map can vary per item. I want to filter the array to only get items where key `b` is present. Can such a thing be achieved using `array_contains` ? I tried but i got error

```
select col1 from mytab where size(col1) > 0 and array_contains(col1, 'b');
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 1:196 Argument type mismatch ''b'': "map<string,string>" expected at function ARRAY_CONTAINS, but "string" is found
```

which is obvious but i tried anyway.

**Update**

i tried

```
select res from mytab LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (col1) c as res where 
 size(col1) > 0 and res is not NULL and length(res) > 0;
```

for this i get

```
{}
{a=1, b=2}
{a=1, b=2}
{}
```

which is good but how can i avoid the empty results i.e. `{}` ?

**Update 2**

I was able to remove the empty results as

```
select res from mytab LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (col1) c as res where 
     size(col1) > 0 and res['b'] is not NULL and length(res['b']) > 0 res <> '{}';
```

Last question is, how to convert `res` from string to a proper map ? i want to have some where condition using keys in res. I tried

```
select str_to_map(res) as st from mytab LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (col1) c as res where 
         size(col1) > 0 and res is not NULL and length(res) > 0 res <> '{}';
```

but i get

```
{"{a=1, b=2}":null}
```

how can i get a proper map ? i just want to be able to filter using the keys of the map. right now this map is being selected as a string

```
select res['b'] from mytab LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE (col1) c as res where 
     size(col1) > 0 and res['b'] is not NULL and length(res) > 0 res['b'] <> '{}' and res['b']=1;
```

but i get

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10033]: Line 1:237 [] not valid on non-collection types ''b'': string

Comment: Did you try to explode an array? `LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(col1) c as res`

Comment: thanks @zealous, please see my update

Comment: Try to add `res != ''`  or `res is not null` in `WHERE` condition

Comment: thanks again, please review the latest update

Comment: could you please print out expected final result, it would help me to understand?